SQL RegEx to confirm a format
I am trying to confirm value of a field to match a certain format.

Here is work in progress, which is passing for most of  values but fails when value_5 is missing (which is optional).
Also is there an elegant way to confirm it?
This SQL is passing but I believe it is not correct:
SELECT REGEXP_LIKE('3-Abc-Def_ValueNumber2_ValueNumber3_ValueNumber4_ValueNumber5','[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Za-z0-9]{3}-[A-Za-z0-9]{3}_[A-Za-z0-9]{3,17}_[A-Za-z0-9]{3,17}_[A-Za-z0-9]{3,20}_[A-Za-z0-9]{3,20}.*');

This one failing, when optional parameter is missing:
SELECT REGEXP_LIKE('3-Abc-Def_ValueNumber2_ValueNumber3_ValueNumber4_ValueNumber5_ValueNumber6','[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Za-z0-9]{3}-[A-Za-z0-9]{3}_[A-Za-z0-9]{3,17}_[A-Za-z0-9]{3,17}_[A-Za-z0-9]{3,20}_[A-Za-z0-9]{3,20}_[A-Za-z0-9]{3,20}.*');

Following  are some other sample values to confirm the solution as well:
'3-ABC-DEF_GHI_ValueNumber2_ValueNumber3_ValueNumber4__ValueNumber6'
'23-ABC-DEF_GHI_ValueNumber2_Value3_ValueNumber4'
'23-AB-DEF_GHIJK_ValueNumber2_ValueNumber3_ValueNumber4_ValueNumber5'


Since the last two sections are optional, just surround them with (...)?.

You have the first field as "1 or 2 digits, dash, 3 alpha, dash, 3 alpha", but the example clearly has 6 alpha for the final part, even though the total length of that example is 13 characters, which violates the 9-10 rule.  Also, you don't have Value_2 in your expression, and you have too many "{3,20}" fields, and you don't have "{3,50}".

Your "other samples" also violate the rules.  "ValueNumber2" shouldn't be in them.  Your strings that start with "GHI" are Value_2.

What DBMS are you using? Different databases use different flavors of regexp.

The example 12-ABC-DEFGHI for value_1 has 11 characters (ignoring the dashes, that needs to be specified), but value 1 is only allowed 9-10 characters. I suspect 12 is supposed to be one "character"?

Thanks Tim & Shwern. Let me correct the typo.
Barmar, I am using Snowflake

Tim Roberts / Schwern
My proposed SQL's regex is too long, there must be cleaner/precise way to do it.
Please share your proposed SQL.

@BeginnerDeveloper Your examples still do not match your rules. For example, 3-ABC-DEF_GHI_ValueNumber2_ValueNumber3_ValueNumber4__ValueNumber6 is invalid because it has 7 values. 3-ABC-DEF is Value 1, GHI is Value 2, ValueNumber2 is Value 3, ValueNumber3 is Value 4, ValueNumber4 is Value 5, Value 6 is blank, ValueNumber6 is a 7th value. Please make sure your rules and examples are consistent and then get back to us.

@Schwern I corrected it but I believe my proposed SQL is incorrect as I am using wrong indexes

@BeginnerDeveloper You missed the sample values at the end.

For value 1, the rule says 9-17 characters with a format of NN-XXX-XXX. Your regex seems to be taking that format literally and matching exactly 1-2 numbers and 2 groups of exactly 3 letters. But then how do you ever reach 17 characters? Is 123-XX-XXXXX valid? What about 1-X-XXXXX? How about 12345-XX-XXXXXXXX?

Used split() to break down value to it's elements and then verified format.
Still love to have a regex solution (if anyone comes up with it)
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE temp_validate_pattern (pixel_value VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO temp_validate_pattern
VALUES 
('03-ABC-DEF_GHI_ValueNumber3_ValueNumber4__ValueNumber6'),
('23-ABC-DEF_GHI_Value3_ValueNumber4'),
('23-ABC-DEF_GHI_ValueNumber3_ValueNumber4_ValueNumber5');

WITH cte_data AS (
    SELECT 
        pixel_value
      , split(pixel_value,'_') AS pixel_element
    FROM temp_validate_pattern
    GROUP BY ALL 
)
, cte_split_data AS (
    SELECT 
        t.pixel_value
      , t.pixel_element[0]::varchar AS value_1
      , t.pixel_element[1]::varchar AS value_2 
      , t.pixel_element[2]::varchar AS value_3
      , t.pixel_element[3]::varchar AS value_4
      , t.pixel_element[4]::varchar AS value_5
      , t.pixel_element[5]::varchar AS value_6
    FROM cte_data t
    GROUP BY ALL
)
, cte_flag_data AS (
    SELECT  
        pixel_value
      , value_1
      , REGEXP_LIKE(value_1,'[0-9]{2}-[A-Za-z0-9]{3}-[A-Za-z0-9]{3,7}') AS value_1_flag
      , value_2
      , REGEXP_LIKE(value_2,'[A-Za-z0-9]{3}') AS value_2_flag
      , value_3
      , REGEXP_LIKE(value_3,'^[A-Za-z0-9]{0,30}$') AS value_3_flag 
      , value_4
      , CASE WHEN value_4 IS NULL THEN TRUE
             ELSE REGEXP_LIKE(value_4,'^[A-Za-z0-9]{0,30}$')                     
        END AS value_4_flag
      , value_5
      , CASE WHEN value_5 IS NULL THEN TRUE
             ELSE REGEXP_LIKE(value_5,'^[A-Za-z0-9]{0,30}$')                     
        END AS value_5_flag
    FROM cte_split_data
)
-- SELECT * FROM cte_flag_data;
SELECT 
    pixel_value
  , (value_1_flag AND value_1_flag AND value_1_flag AND value_1_flag AND value_1_flag) AS valid_campaign
FROM cte_flag_data
ORDER BY 1;


Consider split_to_table, that should replace the need for cte_split_data. Your logic doesn't match your rules, but you've got the basics. You should be able to borrow pieces of the regexes in my answer.

We can make your regexes significantly shorter by using \d for digits and [:alnum:] for alphanumeric. See Regex Character Classes.
Normally we need to anchor regexes at the start and end of the string with ^$. Otherwise you'll match mary had a little lamb 12345-XX-XXXXXXXX_two_three_four and it was delicious. But regexp_like assumes they're there.
The tricky part is your first requirement of 9-17 characters in total where some are numbers and some are alphanumeric. First, let's do the basic requirement for Value 1: the string begins with a group of numbers and two groups of alphanumerics separated by dashes then an underscore.
regexp_like(field, '\d+-[[:alnum:]]+-[[:alnum:]]+_')

Normally to restrict the size of the whole thing we can add a positive look ahead to require 9 to 17 characters before the first _.
regexp_like(field, '(?=.{9,17}_)\d+-[[:alnum:]]+-[[:alnum:]]+_')

But Snowflake does not support positive look-aheads. So we need to do a second regex to confirm the first value's length. We test that it starts with 9 to 17 non-underscore characters before the first underscore: [^_]{9,17}_.
regexp_like(field, '[^_]{9,17}_') and
regexp_like(field, '\d+-[[:alnum:]]+-[[:alnum:]]+_')

With that out of the way, values 2, 3, and 4 are straight-forward variations on [[:alnum:]]{x,y}
regexp_like(field, '[^_]{9,17}_') and
regexp_like(field, '\d+-[[:alnum:]]+-[[:alnum:]]+_[[:alnum:]]{3}_[[:alnum:]]{3,17}_[[:alnum:]]{3,17}')

Values 5 and 6 we add spaces to the character class, [[:alnum:]\s] and make the whole thing optional by wrapping it all, including the underscore, in an optional group: (...)?. (_[[:alnum:]\s]{3,20})?.
regexp_like(field, '[^_]{9,17}_') and
regexp_like(field, '\d+-[[:alnum:]]+-[[:alnum:]]+_[[:alnum:]]{3}_[[:alnum:]]{3,17}_[[:alnum:]]{3,17}(_[[:alnum:]\s]{3,20})?(_[[:alnum:]\s]{3,50})?')

This only works because value 5 is just a shorter version of value 6. If it were the other way around we'd have to get more complicated.
Demonstration. For the purposes of the demonstration I've used the PCRE regex engine and added the implicit ^...$ anchors.

Is this gross? Yes. SQL is not great at string parsing and validation. An alternative approach is to split on _ and validate each piece separately.

Thanks @schwern but unfortunately SQL is not supporting this reges.

@BeginnerDeveloper It's important to get out of the habit of saying "it doesn't work". If there's another error, be sure to provide us with the error and other information to fix the problem; I don't have Snowflake to test on so it's on you. I'm guessing it's the look-aheads. I've updated the answer to remove the look-aheads. Try that and let us know.

Sorry, I forgot to update thread.
I went ahead with SPLIT (as  you  proposed) and got it working (still need small tweaks  though).
Sharing solution.

@BeginnerDeveloper Glad you got it working! I really do think splitting is the better way. Does my updated regex work?
